# image button - no page change

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to call a php file without refreshing the page. The code executes the php file, but the value toid is not being passed along. If i manually query the page then it works fine. The other issue im having is the button needs to be an image with the path src="{ROOT_PATH}mchat/quote.gif"

```
<form id="myform"  method="POST"  class="form_statusinput">
<input type="hidden"  name="toid" id="toid" value="<?php echo {mchatrow.MCHAT_USERNAME}; ?>">
<div id="button_block">
<input type="submit" id="button" value="Enter">
</div>
</form>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("form#myform").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var toid = $("#toid").val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "randomquote.php",
        data: "toid=" + toid,
         });
    });
});
 </script>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: If you could add a fiddle for this it would be helpful to solve the issue

Comment: The event object is passed to the function as a parameter. You should be declaring your anonymous function like this: `$('form').on("submit", function(event){`

Comment: Also, post the relevant PHP code (from executethisscript.php), and I suggest using the jQuery shortcut functions more (aka $.get)

Comment: Make sure to always check the JS console within your browser's devtools - actually always have it open while developing. The problem @PitaJ mentions would have definitely come up as an error.

Comment: It would say something like: `TypeError: undefined is not a function` or `ReferenceError: event is not defined`

Comment: update now i cant get the value toid to pass and the button to be an image ( src="{ROOT_PATH}mchat/quote.gif" )

Comment: I believe the issue to be on the server side

Comment: Why would you think that is the case? I can manually query the link with toid... and the php does everything as intended

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say "if i manually query the page then it works fine", does that mean hitting the endpoint directly like

```
http://yoursite.com/randomquote.php?toid=239439
```

Have you tried sending the data as an object (like this):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "randomquote.php",
    data: { toid: toid }
});
```

That may do the trick.

Comment: "When you say "if i manually query the page then it works fine", does that mean hitting the endpoint directly like" - Yes.